# CSS Wordpress: Change Login default blue color

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I change default blue color for *selected* *button* or *checkmark* in Wordpress standard login page with CSS?

[image: Default blue selected button border and chekmark]

This is the default blue color I mean, used for selected button border and chekmark... I don't mean the normal button border color, but the color around it after you click on it or used for the selected checkmark...

EDIT: ignore customizations in the pic above. Standard Wordpress login is the same:
[image]

Comment: can you provide code for better understating?

Comment: In the pic above I was using a WP plugin to customize login, but it's the same on standard login WP page (blue std color for checkmark and around button):
https://i.ibb.co/8KzT30c/image.png

Comment: I suspect they can't be changed through CSS, until you replace browser input defaults gadgets (especially for the checkmark look)...

Answer (score 0):

For the button, I believe you should use `border: /* Your border code here */`. But if that doesn't work, `outline: /* Your outline code here */`. As for the checkmark, I have created a different coloured checkmark, but it was a custom one. Therefore, I am not sure about an answer for you.